# How to display the rates in bargraph from phpmyadmin to bargraph in android studio(JAVA)?

Tags: java, android, phpmyadmin

**BarrioRate.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".BarrioRate"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.DayNight.ActionBar">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/barrioRate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
            android:text="@string/barrio_crime"
            android:textColor="@color/Poseidon"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/topBarrio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
            android:text="Top 5 Barrio that have a highest Crimes"
            android:textColor="@color/Poseidon"
            android:textSize="18sp"
"/>

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
            android:id="@+id/barChart"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/topBarrio"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**CrimeRate.java**

Get the total of each barrios crime in phpmyadin then display the top 5 highest barrios crime rates in the bar graph with their rates

```
package com.example.mobile;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class BarrioRate extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BarChart barChart;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       

        
        barChart = findViewById(R.id.barChart);


    }
}
```

Barrio.php

count the crime of each barrio then get the total of it then get the rates of it. I just really don't know what code I should use. I am a beginner and this is my first time to create a mobile app

```
<?php
    
    include 'connection.php';
    
    // Create a connection to the database
    $con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbName);

    
    if ($con->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
    }
    
    // SQL query to retrieve crime data
barrio_crime    $sql = "SELECT b, COUNT(*) as count FROM report GROUP BY barrio_crime";
    
    $result = $con->query($sql);
    
    $data = array();
    
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $barrio_crime = $row['barrio_crime'];
            $count = $row['count'];
            $data[] = array("barrio_crime" => $barrio_crime, "count" => $count);
        }
    }
    
    // Close the database connection
    $conn->close();
    
    // Return the data as JSON
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

I expect that barangay that have a highest crime to be displayed in the bar graph. I expect that barangay that have a highest crime to be displayed in the bar graph.